# Wordpress on github pages?

Tags: wordpress, github, github-pages

Is it possible to host a **WordPress** site on **GitHub pages**? I don't know enough about the subject to get it to work... I tried uploading the wordpress 5.5 contents from wordpress.org but it still doesn't work

Comment: GitHub pages is for static websites, no database or php engines that's not possible.

Comment: ou can convert it to a static website if you like then post it to GitHub pages. However, you would lose some functionality

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros how can i convert it? how do i even install it?

Comment: Please search for how to convert wordpress to static website.

Answer (score 1):

Github Pages are for static websites, Wordpress uses **php code** in it which is not supported by Github Pages, Netlify, Firebase, etc.